# Cosa significa "cavilloso" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel romanzo *Storia di chi fugge e di chi resta* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> Quando il dottore si concentrò finalmente su di lei interrogandola a lungo, gli rispose di malavoglia, in dialetto o in un brutto italiano che ricalcava formule dialettali. Spesso dovetti intervenire per ricordarle sintomi che mi aveva riferito o per dar peso a quelli che minimizzava. Infine si sottopose a una visita accuratissima e a esami **cavillosi** con un’espressione corrucciata, come se io e il cardiologo le stessimo facendo un torto.

Ho cercato il termine "cavilloso" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire qual è il significato di "esami cavillosi" nel passaggio precedente. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: Charo, scusami, ma questa domanda mi fa un effetto un po' simile a quello di “inerme”. Trovo che in casi così, una volta noto o appreso il significato di una parola, gli usi figurati o metaforici che ne fa uno specifico autore in uno specifico contesto non siano più una questione linguistica, ma di interpretazione (a volte, come qui, pure abbastanza ovvia, considerando anche la quasi endiadi “visita accuratissima / esami cavillosi”).

Comment: @DaG: Capisco cosa vuoi dire, ma è molto difficile per me, che non sono italiana, capire se si tratta di un uso figurato più o meno comune che non appare nei dizionari oppure di qualcosa inventata dalla autrice. Per di più, come ho detto in un commento alla domanda precedente, si tratta di vocaboli a me sconosciuti e a volte questo mi rende difficile immaginare una possibile interpretazione.

Comment: @DaG - concordo in pieno, il motivo per cui rispondo è che la domanda viene da un NNS. Comunque se si ritiene, o i mods ritengono,  che questo tipo di domande siano off-topic, mi asterrò dal rispondere nel futuro.

Comment: @xxxxxx: Cos'è un NNS?

Comment: Non Native Speaker... scusa, ma è un acronimo molto usato su atri siti.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cavillo](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/C/cavillo.php) è un termine usato principalmente nell'ambito giuridico in riferimento a dettagli  particolari e spesso insoliti usati per rendere un argomento più complesso e difficile da discutere:

> - Argomento sottile, ingegnoso, valido solo in apparenza, sostenuto per alterare, confondere o nascondere una verità: *cercare, usare cavilli; ricorre a ogni sorta di cavilli pur di avere ragione*.

L'uso dell'aggettivo cavilloso nel brano è un'estensione del significato più comune:

***[Cavilloso](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/C/cavilloso.php)***:

> - Che presenta cavilli; che si basa su cavilli tortuosi: una dottrina cavillosa
>     SIN. capzioso, arzigogolato. (Garzanti)

Esami cavillosi nel senso di esami accurati,  dettagliati in maniera esagerata, attenti ai minimi particolari.